# Generated CS class from xml schema

Tags: c#, xml

I did generate C# class form scham using xsd.exe (VS 2010 command prompt),
but when I serialize class to xml file, in the out file I don't have entry for schema.

Serialized xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Dokumenty xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" idSystemuLokalnego="ASD" dataUtworzenia="0001-01-01T00:00:00">
<Wniosek>
    <Beneficjent />
</Wniosek>
```

When I try to validate with schema using code:

```
        //Serilalize xml to string
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        x.Serialize(xw, doc);
        String xml = sw.ToString();

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr);
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add("", "schemas\\SimWniosekApl_v2.0.xsd");
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

        //XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xtr);
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(xtr);

        ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);

        // the following call to Validate succeeds.
        document.Validate(eventHandler);
```

It fails with exception:
 *Additional information: The XmlSchemaSet on the document is either null or has no schemas in it. Provide schema information before calling Validate.*

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to apply the XmlReaderSettings when you create the reader.

That code does nothing with the settings.  The reader has been created already, before the settings are created.  The code simply creates settings and then forgets them.

```
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml); 
    //XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr); 
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings(); 
    settings.Schemas.Add("", "schemas\\SimWniosekApl_v2.0.xsd"); 
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema; 

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xtr,settings); 
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument(); 
    document.Load(reader); 

    ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler); 
    document.Validate(eventHandler);
```

There is a full example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371.aspx